# Subscribing to single reducer with Redux Connect still delivers all reducers to component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux

I have a store with 9 reducers in it. I only want my component to listen to one of them `discoverSearch`. Using shorthand version of `mapStateToProps` this is my code. However, the component is still being delivered all reducers in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

**Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { View, Text, Animated, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const _ = require('lodash')

import colors from '../../Color'
import DiscoverSearchResultChannel from './DiscoverSearchResultChannel'
import DiscoverSearchResultEpisode from './DiscoverSearchResultEpisode'

const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window') 

class DiscoverSearchResultsContainer extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super()

    this.generateResultsList = this.generateResultsList.bind(this)

  }

  generateResultsList(results, type) {
    const components = []
    for (let i = results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      if (type === 'CHANNEL') {
        const result = 
        (<DiscoverSearchResultChannel 
          entry={results[i]} 
          key={`dsearch-${results[i].id}`} 
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
        />)
        components.push(result)
      } else if (type === 'EPISODE') {
        const result = 
        (<DiscoverSearchResultEpisode 
          entry={results[i]}
          key={`dsearch-${results[i].id}`} 
          navigation={this.props.navigation}
        />)

        components.push(result)
      }

    }
    return components
  }

  render() {

    const { episodes, channels } = this.props.discoverSearch.results

    return (
      <Animated.ScrollView 
        style={styles.shell} 
        contentContainerStyle={styles.innerContent}
      >
      <Text style={styles.divider}>Podcasts</Text>
      {
        _.isUndefined(channels) ? null : this.generateResultsList(channels, 'CHANNEL')
      }
      <Text style={styles.divider}>Episodes</Text>
      {
        _.isUndefined(episodes) ? null : this.generateResultsList(episodes, 'EPISODE')
      }
      </Animated.ScrollView> 
    )
  }

}


export default connect(store => (
{ discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch },
  dispatch => dispatch
  ))(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

**Store**

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux'
import { createLogger } from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import promise from 'redux-promise-middleware'

import combinedReducers from './reducers/CombineReducers'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(
  thunk,
  createLogger(),
  promise()
)

export default createStore(combinedReducers, middleware)
```

**DiscoverSearchReducer**

```
const initialState = {
  results: []
}
const DiscoverSearchReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {

  let newState    

  switch (action.type) {

    case 'DISCOVER_SEARCH_REQUEST_OUT':
      // TODO
      break
    case 'DISCOVER_SEARCH_RETURN':
      newState = {
        ...state,
        results: action.payload
      }
      break
    default:
      return state 
  }

  return newState
}
```

**Reducers**

```
export default combineReducers({
  network: NetworkReducer,
  audioPlayer: AudioPlayerReducer,
  fileHandler: FileHandlerReducer,
  currentTrack: CurrentTrackReducer,
  trackQueue: TrackQueueReducer,
  asyncStatus: AsyncStatusReducer,
  makeClip: MakeClipReducer,
  userProfile: UserProfileReducer,
  scrollListener: ScrollListenReducer,
  userClips: UserClipsReducer,
  discoverSearch: DiscoverSearchReducer,
})
```

**App Entry**

```
class App extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {

    // TODO
    // Initialize Firebase => get UID then... 
      store.dispatch(fetchUser('7713BNBNPODPIE'))
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    TrackPlayer()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store} >
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
          <Navigation />
          <BottomPlayer />
        </View>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

The connect piece of Redux is a little new to me so I might be missing something obvious?

***Edits:*** 
Added App.js entry point
Added full `DiscoverSearchResultsContainer` component minus `styles`

Comment: You mean to say that you able to access `nextProps.network`, `nextProps.audioPlayder` etc in your component? As far as I know, It shouldn't happen as you have just returned `discoverSearch` from the `mapStateToProps`.

Comment: Try do this in your connect `connect(({ discoverSearch }) => ({ discoverSearch }), dispatch => dispatch)(MyComponnet)`.

Comment: @HardikModha Correct, I can access all of the reducers

Comment: @G4bri3l No dice on that, getting a build error if I `export default`

Comment: The Store and the Reducers look fine to me. Usually my `connect` though looks like this:

`export default connect(
  state => ({ someProp: state.someProp }),
  dispatch => ({ actions: bindActionCreators(myActions, dispatch) })
 )(MyComponnet)`

Comment: `combineReducers` is pretty straightforward and I don't see anything wrong, your Store seems fine too, my suggestion would be to take some stuff out add it again and see what goes wrong, maybe keep one only middleware, then try only a few reducers in your `combineReducers` and check what props are passed to your component, ... and so on.

Comment: Can you make a Reproducable demo for your problem, you code seems fine. Also a full definition of `DiscoverSearchResultsContainer` might also be useful for debugging

Comment: Added full `DiscoverSearchResultsContainer` component minus styles. I have to think about how to efficiently create an example. This project is pretty big

Comment: and where exactly are you able to access all the reducers

Comment: Could you post `DiscoverSearchReducer`?

Comment: Added `DiscoverSearchReducer`

Comment: @PhilAndrews, you did not answer, where exactly are you able to access all the reducers

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Sorry, I can access them anywhere within the component, `this.props`, `nextProps`. Every reducer is being passed to every component hooked to `connect`

Comment: Did you try @OlliM answer, I think he is probably correct

Comment: I'm working on it right now. It doesn't build with the code he provided. So I'm trying to figure out what's missing

Comment: @OlliM `Maximum call stack exceeded`

Comment: @OlliM I got it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in your connect function:

```
export default connect(store => (
  { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch },
    dispatch => dispatch
  ))(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

You have parenthesis wrong, this is equivalent to:

```
connect(store => {
  // this does nothing
  { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch };
  return dispatch => dispatch;
})(...)
```

Which is actually the same as

```
connect(state => state)(...)
```

What you probably meant to write was:

```
connect(store = ({ discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch }), 
  dispatch => dispatch)(...)
```

EDIT: Remove unnecessary dispatch

As commented, mapping the dispatch is useless, you can just do

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({ discoverSearch: state.discoverSearch });
connect(mapStateProps)(Component);
```

Comment: This is mostly right. Mapping `dispatch` is actually unnecessary and ends up causing a build error. Removing `dispatch => dispatch` maps everything correctly, including `dispatch`. Is `dispatch` passed down from `Provider`?

Comment: @PhilAndrews `dispatch` is implicitly passed by the `connect()` (from the Provider). `mapDispatchToProps` passes action creators already bound to `dispatch` so you don't need to call it explicitly on the passed creators.

Comment: Edited the answer - better to have the correct case instead of the minimum change to make the original work.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to way use connect is to separate out `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` into their own function so as to avoid making syntactical errors and if you are anyways returning dispatch as the second parameter you might as well not use it since if the second parameter to connect is empty, dispatch is returned by default.

According to the **[connect documentaion](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options)**

> `[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or
>   Function):` If an object is passed, each function inside it is assumed
>   to be a Redux action creator. An object with the same function names,
>   but with every action creator wrapped into a dispatch call so they may
>   be invoked directly, will be merged into the component’s props.
>
> If a function is passed, it will be given dispatch as the first
>   parameter. It’s up to you to return an object that somehow uses
>   dispatch to bind action creators in your own way. (Tip: you may use
>   the `bindActionCreators()` helper from Redux.)
>
> If your `mapDispatchToProps` function is declared as taking two
>   parameters, it will be called with dispatch as the first parameter and
>   the props passed to the connected component as the second parameter,
>   and will be re-invoked whenever the connected component receives new
>   props. (The second parameter is normally referred to as ownProps by
>   convention.)
>
> If you do not supply your own `mapDispatchToProps` function or object
>   full of action creators, the default `mapDispatchToProps`
>   implementation just injects dispatch into your component’s props.

You could use your connect statmeent like

```
const mapStateToProps = store => {
    return { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

When you use connect like

```
export default connect(store => (
      { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch },
        dispatch => dispatch
))(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

You actually have your `()` at the wrong place as you want to return `{ discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch }` and not `{ discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch }, dispatch => dispatch`. It should be

```
export default connect(store => (
      { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch })
)(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

The above snippet would be the same as

```
export default connect(store => {
          return { discoverSearch: store.discoverSearch }
      }
)(DiscoverSearchResultsContainer)
```

which is what you need. However you must go with the first approach

Comment: @PhilAndrews, please check the explanation in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that your `DiscoverSearchReducer` is returning a new object for each dispatch, even on a no-op?

```
function reduceSomething(state, action) {
     if action.type == "forMe":    
       return {action.payload}
     else
       return {...state}
}
```

rather than:

```
 return state
```

Because *the former* will give you a new object for every dispatch, with the expected content, but connect will be unable to suppress passing props to your component.

It's a weird one but it matches your symptoms.